# How can I set up IntelliJ IDEA to work on a mixed Java/C++ project

Tags: java, c++, maven, intellij-idea, java-native-interface

I have an existing Java project using Maven for building in IntelliJ IDEA.  I am looking to add several new classes to this project that will be implemented using C++ and JNI native methods.  How should I configure my IDE and build tools to make this work?  I'm open to changing from Maven to another build tool if it makes it easier, although I admit I have previously found Gradle confusing and would rather avoid it unless it would make a substantial difference.

Also are there any plugins or other modifications that will improve the experience of editing C++ files in IntelliJ IDEA?  I'm aware that there was once a third-party C++ plugin that is no longer supported in recent versions of IDEA, but is there another way of doing this?

*For clarification* as stated in the comments, I am not specifically looking for off-site resources.  I am happy to accept any solution that allows me to work on a mixed Java/C++ project using JetBrains products.  As only a small portion of my project is in C++, I do not need complete C++ support (e.g. I do not require debugger integration, as I am happy to switch IDEs for such occasionally-used features, but I don't want to have to switch for day-to-day actions such as editing and rebuilding files).  If doing so involves installing a plugin then so be it, but as I stated in the comments I have been led to believe that simple Maven configuration changes will allow me to build such a project, but unfortunately the site I found this information on didn't make clear what the changes should be.

Comment: _@occipita_ _"Also are there any plugins or other modifications that will improve the experience of editing C++ files in IntelliJ IDEA?"_ At least asking for such off-site resources makes your question _off-topic_ here. So why wonder about downvotes? Better act somehow to make your question _on-topic_ and avoid close votes!

Comment: I'm not asking for off-site resources. I'm asking for experiences about using software and information about how to configure it.

Comment: I don't see how kinda _"experience reports"_ would be on topic here. Outcome: Endless amount of (mostly unconcise) answers, or "I have that problem too" stuff.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I really don't understand the problem.  It's a simple question about how to use "software tools commonly used by programmers" as listed in the help section about valid topics.  Such questions usually have answers that involve either modifying configuration settings or installing plugins that add additional features, which is what I was requesting, and somebody who has done it before is likely to know what those changes/plugins are, which is what I meant by "experiences" in my comment above.

Comment: _"I'm aware that there was once a third-party C++ plugin that is no longer supported in recent versions of IDEA, but is there an alternative to this?"_ Asks for 3rd party resources, _off-topic_. End of discussion from my side here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't agree. If someone says "there was once a plugin that would solve my problem, but it is no longer supported, is there an alternative to this?", then this is not asking for plugins, it is asking for a solution.

Comment: I am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

**The C/C++ plugin is available in the IntelliJ Plugin Repository and is actually not developed by Jetbrains, but by a third party called AdvancedTools**, and has long not been updated. [C/C++ plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1373-c-c-)  I'm not sure if that is related to the release of CLion, e.g. IntelliJ bought out the plugin to serve as the foundation of CLion.

*It might make your IntellijIDEA crash at startup. If this happens, just delete the plugin from the folder it has been installed*

Check out this Official IntelliJ website for more information [IntelliJ Multi-platform](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/discover-intellij-idea.html#IntelliJ-IDEA-editions)

Comment: AFAIK, CLion doesn't support Java projects, though, so I don't see that as an option, and comments I've seen elsewhere suggest that this can be done via a Maven plugin, but I've not found any details about it. See, e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/706okm/users_of_intellij_do_you_know_a_good_workflow_to/

Comment: The C/C++ plugin is available in the IntelliJ Plugin Repository and is actually not developed by Jetbrains but by a third party called AdvancedTools.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that it isn't on the list of available plugins if that helps. It does look like it has been removed. Perhaps Jetbrains didn't want the competition for CLion.

CLion is better because you have an IDEE dedicated to C/C++, and this way, you can "personalize" it better.

As listed in the CLion FAQ page, there is currently no official standalone plugin for C/C++ editing available for IntelliJ IDEA. Just as with some other products such as Jetbrains AppCode, Jetbrains is currently keeping CLion as an exclusively paid product, without a free community edition, as indicated in this forum post.

Answer (score 2):

The C/C++ plugin is actually developed by a third party, but I think that it is not reliable, Its usage may crash your application as it is outdated.
[C/C++ plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1373-c-c-)